# Select all children except those in a marked group with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list structure like this (note the two lists with .browser class and one of them with data-click="yes")

```
<ul class="browser" data-click="yes">
<li><a href="#">Group 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item_1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item_2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item_3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Group_2</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item_4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item_5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item_6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Group_3</a>
            <ul class="browser">
                <li><a href="#">Item_1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item_2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Group_4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Item_1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item_2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item_3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item_3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to assign an on click action with jQuery to the A elements within the `<ul class="browser" data-click="yes">` element, however I do not want this behavior to propagate further to the A elements in the child element `<ul class="browser">`. Moreover, it is important for me to keep the class .browser for both those lists.

I tried to use :not selector in the following way

```
$("body").on("click", "UL.browser[data-click='yes'] :not(.browser) A", function (event) {
// do something
});
```

and many other variants, but without success. It is also important for me to use the structure with appending the event to body since I am changing the structure dynamically.

I found many variants of this problem here, however none of them is quite the same and they did not work for me. I sense that I misunderstand the :not selector in some way, however I still can't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to handle the click on `a` elements inside `ul.browser[data-click='yes']` but not inside an internal `.browser` element :

```
$("body").on("click", "ul.browser[data-click='yes'] a:not(.browser .browser *)", function (event) {
  // do something
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/tdRLM/)

Comment: Thank you, this is it. I will have to look deeper in the behavior of the :not operator

Answer (score 3):

I understand you only want to attach the click event to the "first" level of `<a>` which are children of a "browser" with data-click set to "yes", you can easily do that by only selecting direct childs:

```
$("body").on("click", "ul.browser[data-click='yes'] > li > a", function (event) {
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was thinking about this option, however I want the rule to work also in the deeper levels

Comment: This also works for deeper levels and is more optimal, selecting direct childs makes the node selection more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the optimal way but should work:

```
$('ul.browser').each(function()
{
   if($(this).data('click') === 'yes')
   {
       $(this).on('click', function(e)
       {
            //Stuff
       });   
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to enable click event function for all `<a>` tags inside `<ul>` having class `.browser` with attribute `data-click="yes"` and you want to exclude all the other `<a>` tags that comes under internal `<ul>` tag having class `.browser` .

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("body").on("click", "ul.browser[data-click='yes']  li a:not(.browser .browser *)",function(){
    alert("hi");
  });

});
```

The above code explains => add click function for all `<a>` tags that comes inside `<li>` tags whose parent is `<ul>` tag having class `.browser` and attribute `data-click='yes'` and don't add click event for any of the tags having hierarchy .browser .browser